# ajax HtmlEditorExtender width issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax, htmleditorextender

While using `ajax HtmlEditorExtender` i am experiencing a wierd problem. i.e. The `width` attribute is gone and the image shrinks.

 Initially my `textbox` which is associated with `HtmlEditorExtender` has this text

```
txtMessage.Text = "<span style=\" padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; width:100%; \"><img src=\"../images/img4layout2.png\" width=\"675px\" height=\"300px\" ></span><span style=\"font-weight: normal;\">Some text here.</span>";
```

and the image looks like this.
[image]

When i click any `dropdown` on page or any other control the source of `HtmlEditorExtender` changes mysteriously to this (There is no `width` attribute now)

```
  <span style=" padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; width:100%; "><img src="../images/img4layout2.png" height="300px"></span><span style="font-weight: normal;">Some text here.</span>
```

and Finally the image looks like this.
[image]

i am not using any `javascript` on this page.

Answer (score 0):

By design, the AjaxControlToolkit removes the width, class and id attributes of html elements added to the content of the HtmlEditorExtender. You can download the source code of the toolkit and make some minor modifications to stop this from happening.

Have a look at [Yuriy Rozhovetskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360171/yuriy-rozhovetskiy)'s answer to [HTMLEditorExtender removes “class”, “id” attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881594/htmleditorextender-removes-class-id-attributes/15936057#15936057).